# Enlarge Cancel PopUP for no Scroll/cutoff in angular

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

In the component.html
I changed the width and height

```
**<div *ngIf ="showIframe>
<iframe [src]="" class="" width="680px" height="375px"> 
</div>**
```

And in the component.scss , changed

```
*****modal-content
{
width:700px
height :500px
overflow: hidden
}*****
```

still dont see the expected result.
Any help on this?